# Django List from empty models got TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: django-templates

Sorry for my poor English, I'm working around several days and I'm blocked, I clean my develop/debug database and after that my code that just didn't work any more.

I'm working for around to understand the reason and how to solve, but no clue. Ask for any path to go to solve this situation and help me.

I know I'm doing something wrong because only did:

```
    ./manage.py --fork contractos zero
    clean all migrations data on contractos/migrations (except init.py)
    ./manage.py --fake
    ./manage.py makemigrations
    ./manage.py migrate
    ./manage.py runserver
```

```
<code>
my list.py
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from contractos.models import Contracto


def list(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff and not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404

    contractos_list = Contracto.objects.all() #.order_by("empresa")
    paginator = Paginator(contractos_list, 10)  # Show 25 contacts per page

    page_request_var = 'lista'
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)

    try:
        contractos = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        #If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            contractos = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        #If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            contractos = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        "object_list" : contractos,
        "title": "Lista de Contractos",
        "page_request_var": page_request_var,
    }
    return render(request, "contractos/list.html", context)


**my list.html**
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1">
        <h1>Contractos {{ title }}</h1>
        <div class="row">
            {% for obj in object_list %}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>
                                <a href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}'>{{ obj.empresa }} </a><br />
                                {% if obj.logo %}
                                    <img src="{{ obj.logo.url }}" class="img-responsive"/>
                                {% endif %}
                                <small>criado  {{ obj.timestamp|timesince }}</small><br />
                                <small>alterado em {{ obj.updated|timesince }}</small><br />
                            </h3>
                            {{ obj.nfic }} <br/>
                            {{ obj.descricao|linebreaks|truncatechars:60 }}
                            <p>...</p>
                            <p><a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Detalhes</a>
                                <!--a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a--></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {% cycle "" "<div class='col-sm-12'><hr/></div></div><div class='row'>" %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <div class="pagination">
            <span class="step-links">
                {% if object_list.has_previous %}
                    <a href="?{{ page_request_var }}=1">Primeira</a>
                    <a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ object_list.previous_page_number }}">Anterior</a>
                {% endif %}

                <span class="current">
                    {% if object_list.number %}
                        Pagina {{ object_list.number }} de {{ object_list.paginator.num_pages }}.
                    {% endif %}
                </span>

                {% if object_list.has_next %}
                    <a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ object_list.next_page_number }}">Seguinte</a>
                    <a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ object_list.paginator.num_pages }}">Ultima</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}

**my models.py**

from __future__ import unicode_literals
import uuid

from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

STATUS_CHOICES = [
    ('a', 'Activo'),
    ('s', 'Suspenso'),
    ('c', 'Cancelado'),
    ('t', 'Terminado'),
]

def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "contractos/%s/%s" % (instance.nfic, filename)

# Create your models here.
class Contracto(models.Model):
    slug = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    nfic = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='PT000000000', unique=True)
    empresa = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    descricao = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='a')
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
                null=True,
                blank=True,
                width_field="width_field",
                height_field="height_field"
                )
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.empresa

    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse("contractos:details", kwargs={"uuid": self.slug})


    class Meta:
        ordering = ["empresa"]
        db_table = ["Contractos"]

and the error I got when try rendering list.py are:
**Environment:**

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/contractos/

Django Version: 1.10.4
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'contractos']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in validate_number
  34.             number = int(number)

**During handling of the above exception (int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'), another exception occurred:**

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/src/contractos/views/list.py" in list
  20.         contractos = paginator.page(page)

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in page
  50.         number = self.validate_number(number)

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in validate_number
  36.             raise PageNotAnInteger('That page number is not an integer')

**During handling of the above exception (That page number is not an integer), another exception occurred:**

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in count
  72.             return self.object_list.count()

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in count
  369.         return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_count
  476.         number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_aggregation
  457.         result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  824.             sql, params = self.as_sql()

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  369.             extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in pre_sql_setup
  46.         self.setup_query()

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in setup_query
  36.             self.query.get_initial_alias()

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_initial_alias
  879.             alias = self.join(BaseTable(self.get_meta().db_table, None))

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in join
  921.         alias, _ = self.table_alias(join.table_name, create=True)

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in table_alias
  689.         alias_list = self.table_map.get(table_name)

**During handling of the above exception (unhashable type: 'list'), another exception occurred:**

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/src/contractos/views/list.py" in list
  23.             contractos = paginator.page(1)

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in page
  50.         number = self.validate_number(number)

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in validate_number
  39.         if number > self.num_pages:

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  35.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in num_pages
  84.         if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  35.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in count
  77.             return len(self.object_list)

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  238.         self._fetch_all()

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1087.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql()

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  824.             sql, params = self.as_sql()

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  369.             extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in pre_sql_setup
  46.         self.setup_query()

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in setup_query
  36.             self.query.get_initial_alias()

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_initial_alias
  879.             alias = self.join(BaseTable(self.get_meta().db_table, None))

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in join
  921.         alias, _ = self.table_alias(join.table_name, create=True)

File "/home/gwo/Projects/paas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in table_alias
  689.         alias_list = self.table_map.get(table_name)

**Exception Type: TypeError at /contractos/
Exception Value: unhashable type: 'list'**
</code>
</pre>
```

So I only clean my data from database to restart populate then again with test information to demonstrated the project to our customer, that as you can imagine I had to cancel!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a function called `list` because it's a python keyword. Change that to something else and it will work. Also you should avoid naming your file `list` etc.